# GD Star Rating - Thumbs Up/Down Size

Tags: wordpress, rating, rating-system

Using [GD Star Rating Wordpress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/).

---

I'm having an extremely tough time trying to figure out how to do something as simple as resizing the rating button.

I have an image that I want to use as thumbs up/down, but it's width is 232px instead of the default max 40px.

Has anyone accomplished resizing the stars/thumbs past 40px or am I the only one in the world with this problem?

---

To put it simply:

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new image width is 232px, so the code should be:

```
width:232px !important;height:232px !important;
```

But can you be more specific about what issue you are having?
new image being cut off? or is it not resized at all when you view it on browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it via css use `width:40px !important;height:40px !important;`

comment-> It would help if you paste a link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I know how can you change the size of thumb.

Go to : plugins/gd-star-rating/css/gdsr.css.php line:183

you found this:

```
echo sprintf(".gdt-size-%s.gdthumb, .gdt-size-%s.gdthumb a, .gdt-size-%s.gdthumb div { width: %spx; height: %spx; }\r\n", $size, $size, $size, $size, $size);
```

change it:

```
echo sprintf(".gdt-size-%s.gdthumb, .gdt-size-%s.gdthumb a, .gdt-size-%s.gdthumb div { width: 232px; height: 232px ; }\r\n", $size, $size, $size, $size, $size);
```

change: width and height , after that change the image size.